# Can some one give be a sample code how to add a request handler to a HttpServer Object in dart?

Tags: dart

I am very new to the dart programming any help is appreciated.

```
void main() {
  var server = new HttpServer();
  server.listen('127.0.0.1', 8080);
  server.
  addRequestHandler(
  accept(HttpRequest function) => acceptInput(request, response), handler);
 }
```

I want to add the function below to the request handler.
**server.addrequestHandler()**
I would like to do this so that I can add many request handlers as such including one for websockets
A sample or a tutorial would be very helpful.

I want to keep each handler in a separate function just for simplicity.

```
void acceptInput(HttpRequest request,HttpResponse response){
  print(request.connectionInfo.toString());
  print(request.queryParameters.toString());
  response.outputStream.write('Hello dude'.charCodes);
  response.outputStream.close();
}
```

**Note:I know my void main code is wrong I need help to make it correct so that it incorporates the acceptInput Function.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you're really close.

Try this:

```
  var server = new HttpServer();
  server.addRequestHandler(
      (req) => req.path == '/save',
      handleSave);
  server.addRequestHandler(
      (req) => req.path == '/delete',
      handleDelete);
  server.defaultRequestHandler = new StaticFileHandler(basePath).onRequest;
```

Where `handleSave` and `handleDelete` are just functions, like:

```
handleSave(HttpRequest req, HttpResponse resp) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks,this has helped me create more than one httprequest handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for a web server that serves files and handles web socket connections:

https://github.com/dart-lang/web-components-code-lab/blob/master/step04/bin/chat_server.dart

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out at my implementation of [Express.dart](https://github.com/mythz/DartExpress/blob/master/Express.dart) which is an Express-like web framework that fits in a single file so it's an easy read.

Check out the [HttpServer docs](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io/HttpServer.html) to see the correct signatures for each method. This is the API for addRequestHandler:

```
abstract addRequestHandler(
    bool matcher(HttpRequest request), 
    void handler(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
)
```

The first parameter is whether this should handle the request, whilst the 2nd argument is the handler that will handle the request if the matcher is true.

So a Http app in Dart would look like:

```
var server = new HttpServer();

server.addRequestHandler(
   (HttpRequest req) => true, 
   acceptInput);

server.listen('127.0.0.1', 8080);
```

Comment: thanks so if I am using websockets bool matcher will take the websocket and the handler will be my function which I created.Thanks for that answer that was what I was looking for :)