# How to deploy Dart server to IIS

Tags: dart, iis, deployment, dart-shelf, dart-server

I want to deploy a basic dart server that uses shelf to an IIS server.

I ran the command dart compile exe and tried to place the executable along with the web.config file in a file system. I set up the workpool with the settings I need. I have a DNS ready which is mywebsite.reu.po and set up the proper bindings for it. It gives me a 503 error something about handlers. The server host name is localhost and the port is whatever APSNET_PORT is. If nothing is found in that port, then it grabs port 4000.

Here is what I have in my web.config file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath=".\server.exe" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on dart. But 503 error means application pool stopped. Maybe something wrong make application pool stopped. You can check event viewer to know error message. Regard to deploy dart to IIS. You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834803/how-would-i-go-about-running-the-dart-vm-on-a-windows-server).

Comment: Thank you, @BruceZhang! Your post did help figured this out.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the solution for this. I had to change the identifier for the pool since there are multiple admin accounts for the IIS. However, only one account has the ability to do hosting. Go to the pool, advance settings, and change the identifier with the right admin credentials.